# css animation plays with external style sheet on load

Tags: html, css

I have an external style sheet that contains transitions. When the page loads the transitions animate.

When I move the transitions from the external style sheet and place them in the header of my html file, the animations don't animate on page load (Which is what I want).

What can I do to stop the transitions from animating when placed in an external style sheet?

Here is some example css:

```
label {
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

When this is in a `css` file, the font goes from the page size to the css file size.

When this is in the header in a `<style>` tag it doesn't do anything.

Comment: could you share the web page, please?

Comment: It is on my local machine there is no page for it.

Comment: I think its related to the exact place the css definition is (within your HTML - before or after any other css definitions, doesn't really matter if they are in CSS file or in `<style>` tag)

Comment: @Dekel write an answer, don't use the comments.

Comment: @Soviut, without looking at the complete code any answer will just be a wild guess... if the question will have more code/example it will be easier to help.

Comment: Then ask for clarification, don't post wild guesses in comments for people to get confused by.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the stylesheets are loading synchronously, while the external sheets load asynchronously. When they load synchronously, transitions aren't triggered because the DOM only has to draw once; There's nothing to transition from. Meanwhile, the few milliseconds it takes to load a stylesheet externally requires the DOM to be redrawn again once it loads.

In this case, you should be using animations, not transitions. Animations will run on start no matter what.

```css
@keyframes slide-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0%;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.animate-me {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  
  animation: slide-in 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="animate-me">animate me on load</div>
```

If you really do need transitions, you'll need some javascript to apply a class after at least one frame delay.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // apply class to elements
}, 0);
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work... It looks like I had to set the parent element to `display: inline-block`, I guess it was somehow affecting it. Looks like it had nothing to do with the style sheet being external.